# How can I make my app show up under "complete action with"?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

When an application uses an another application to complete an action then usually (if no default was set) you get the option to choose an application: E.g: the Twitter app gives you the option to chose a camera app to take a picture.

Now, how can I make my application that I built show up in this list? How would you do that in case of taking a picture, for example?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), define an IntentFilter in your activity with an action and a MIME type. For example, taking a picture/selecting an image:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/take_picture">
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
             <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: can you please make this more clear. Where do I have to add the intentfilter (manifest?) and do I just add this code? Because that does not work

Comment: Yes, add the intentfilter in the activity of your manifest that is capable of handling that action. 
`<activity android:name="myCamera" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`

In that activity you should return the URI of the picture taken as if the activity was called using startActivityForResult()

Comment: it is still not working. Can you PLEASE show an entire snapshot of your manifest

Comment: No, but here you can check the full process http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: it is still not working. So I wont't be able to accept your answer and will have to wait for a better answer